# Android Bluetooth API connect to multiple devices at the same time

Tags: android, bluetooth

It is possible to connect simultaneously to multiple bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a test app about a week ago that connected to two separate serial devices simultaneously. It commanded both of them independently and the performance was awesome.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I decided to take a different route and completely forgot that I posted a question here.

Comment: Hi Brad. Did you use standard Android SDK Bluetooth connection functions and methods for it?